# Prove that $f$ must be divisible by $3$ for all integers if there are is an $m$ such that $f(m),f(m+1)$ and $f(m+2)$ are divisible by $3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with the property that there exist three
>   consecutive integers $m, m+1$ and $m+2$ such that $f(m),f(m+1)$ and
>   $f(m+2)$ are divisible by $3$. Prove that $f$ must be divisible by $3$
>   for all integers.

So to my understanding:

Is $f(x)=f(m)+f(m+1)+f(m+2)$ ?

However, here is how I proceed

I worked with examples, so let $m=1, m+1=2, m+2=3$

Let's say $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ and if I plug $1$ then I get $3$ and if I plug $2$ I get $7$ which is not divisible by $3$. If I plug $3$ I get $13$ which is not divisible by $3$.

I'm guessing that $f(x)$ has to be a specific polynomial.

I'm pretty much stuck. Any guides ?

Comment: Surely f(x) has to be a specific polynomial.It has a unique property mentioned.

Comment: Where did you get this? As stated it is blatantly false.

Comment: @Aniket What do you mean with unique property? There are multiple (infinitely many, in fact) polynomials $f$ that statistify.

Comment: @PaxKivimae It is true provided that $f$ has integer coefficients.

Comment: It's definitely not the case that $f(x)$ must be a specific polynomial. $3g(x)$ satisfies the conditions for any polynomial $g(x)$ with integer coefficients, for example.

Comment: All polynomials in the form $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-k)+3$ with $k \in \mathbb Z$ statistify.

Comment: @wythagoras Don't get me wrong.By specific polynomial, I didn't refer to a particular polynomial. I meant a certain class of polynomials only, like the one mentioned by Dylan, and that along with the property mentioned .

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You have to use the rule that if $P$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients  and $a,b,n$ integers, then if $a \equiv b \mod n$, then $P(a) \equiv P(b) \mod n$.

**Note:** It doesn't hold if $P$ does not have integer coefficients, because it does not hold for $$P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-0.28)+3$$ for example. Your question currently doesn't require  integer coefficients.

Comment: It will still hold for your example. For any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, either $x-1, x-2,$ or $x - 3$ will be divisible by $3$ because $x-1, x-2,$ and $x - 3$ form a complete system of residues $mod 3$. Then, let's say $3|(x-1)$ so $x - 1 = 3k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. By substitution,

\begin{equation}
P(x) = 3k(x - 2)(x - 3)(x - 0.5) + 3
\end{equation}

and a $3$ can be factored from both terms, so $P(x)$ is divisible by $3$. 

Similarly if $3|(x-2)$ or $3|(x-3)$.

Comment: @JacobCheverie You are right, I changed it. Now it will not hold, because $P$ is generally not an integer.

Comment: If my logic was correct, then it still shouldn't hold. But it's interesting because it doesn't look to me like it should hold in your example.

Comment: I think it is implied in the question that the polynomial takes integer values at integer points (which is admittedly weaker than having integer coefficients). Your counterexample does not have that property.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(m), f(m+1),$ and $f(m+2)$ are divisible by $3$ for consecutive integers $m, m+1,$ and $m+2$, then $f$ has to be divisible by $3$ for any integer. The reason is that $m, m+1,$ and $m+2$ form a complete system of residues $mod(3)$. Thus, every element of the system of residues is going to be mapped to some number divisible by $3$, so $3|f(x)$ is true for every $x$.